# Avoid reducing of stock when item is added to cart

Tags: magento-1.7

For example, there is one pair of shoes in stock. User "X" adds them to cart. Later, when user "Y" tries to add same shoes to cart - he gets a message "product is out of stock".

Is there any way to reduce the stock only after order is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock is reduced only after the order is place.
This is the default behavior. Unless you have some extension that reduces the stock when you add it to the cart.
Also keep in mind that the current quantity in the cart is taken into consideration when add a product.

Let's take this case.
You have a product with qty = 3.
You add qty 1 to the cart. Everything is OK.
Then you add it again in qty 2. Now you have product P in qty 3 in cart.
You try to add it again to the cart in qty 1.
You get an error because the max available qty is 3 and you try to have a total of 4 in the cart.

Comment: You're right, I haven't cleared cookies properly. Thank you very much for help, as always.